# Как сгрупировать строки и убрать NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм данных:

```
Date      | ID | A   | B
01.01.2021| 1  | NaN | bbb
01.01.2021| 1  | aaa | NaN
01.01.2021| 2  | NaN | bbb
01.01.2021| 2  | aaa | NaN
01.01.2021| 3  | NaN | bbb
............................
```

Как можно убрать NaN и сгрупировать строки по ID?

Пробовал с использованием `pd.notnull`, делал 2 фрейма, а потом их склеивал. Но это, как-то мне кажется, не совсем верно и корректно.

Может есть какое-то решение этого вопроса?

Comment: приведите в вопросе результат, которий вы хотите получить...

Comment: "сгрупировать в 1 строку по ID" --  если я правильно понял, то groupby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```
res = df.groupby(["ID", "Date"]).first().reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [263]: res
Out[263]: 
   ID       Date    A    B
0   1 2021-01-01  aaa  bbb
1   2 2021-01-01  aaa  bbb
2   3 2021-01-01  NaN  bbb
```

Comment: Да оно спасибо большое